# jquery how to make each function to call finally updating all?

Tags: jquery

i have a function to loop through all the 'li' element and collect the data. as well i am pushing all the data to array. once the all 'li' loop through finish, i need to call a function one time with updated data?

my present code like this: but it calling 3 times my function, because it gets 3 times the condition. the function works fine, i am wrong to call the function, any good suggestion to make it to call one time, after finishing all the loop.

```
var pieIndex = [];
$('button.pieDraw', $(accordionBox)).live('click', function () { //done button
    var uls = $(accordionSec.accorGeography).find('ul');

    $.each(uls, function (i, val) {
        pieIndex = []; //i am clearing the array each time to get new value
        var currentLI = $(val).find('li');
        $(currentLI).each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('c_on')) { // this is finding the class 3 times. it's fine
                var functionName = pieFunction[$(this).parent().attr('title') + 'Pie'].fun;
                pieIndex.push($(this).attr('data-index')); // at the last i am getting 1,2,3 it's correct.
                generatePieURL(functionName, curQI, crrentMonth, currentYear, pieIndex);
                //it is calling 3 times. i need only one time to call..
            }
        })

    })

});
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just take your function call out of the inner `.each` loop:

```
    $(currentLI).each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('c_on')) { 
            var functionName = pieFunction[$(this).parent().attr('title') + 'Pie'].fun;
            pieIndex.push($(this).attr('data-index')); 
        }
    })
    generatePieURL(functionName, curQI, crrentMonth, currentYear, pieIndex);
```

Comment: i did as like you explained, but the pieIndex.push value i am not get. so i return the pieIndex after the push, till i am not get the value

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generatePieURL` after your `each`, because the jQuery `each` is synchronous.

So:

```
var functionName; // will be filled in the following loop (only if the output will be the same at each loop
$(currentLI).each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('c_on'))
    ...
    return false; // to stop the each, if not needed anymore
})
if pieIndex.length > 0
  generatePieUrl(...)
```